# I have two action need to pass in to my onClick button on react.js. But When I do, I fail to get it? is it any solution to solve it?

Tags: reactjs, button, onclick, bootstrap-modal, buttonclick

Consider the code below:

```
                    <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="danger" onClick={()=>{
                        {this.props.onHide};
                        {()=> this.setState({userDetailModalShow: true})};
                    }}>User Detail</Button>
                      <Button variant="danger" onClick={this.props.onHide}>close</Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
```

So When I click on User Detail Button, the modal of user detail will show out, at the same time, will hide the previous modal. But I get error on that multiple action on onClick of user detail. Is my way of code is wrong? or is it there is anyother  way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
   // use handler function is cleaner
   handleClickUserDetail = (e) => {
     e.persist(); // persist the event to send it to onHide if needed
     e.preventDefault();

     this.props.onHide(e); // send the event to onHide if needed
     this.setState({ userDetailModalShow: true });
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <Modal.Footer>
         <Button 
           variant="danger" 
           onClick={this.handleClickUserDetail}
          >
           User Detail
          </Button>
          <Button 
            variant="danger" 
            onClick={this.props.onHide}
          >
            close
          </Button>
       </Modal.Footer>
     );
   }
```

Hope it helps ;)!

Comment: No problem, I am glad that could help :)!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try like this?

```
<Modal.Footer>
   <Button variant="danger" onClick={()=>{
       this.props.onHide();
       this.setState({userDetailModalShow: true});
   }}>User Detail</Button>
   <Button variant="danger" onClick={this.props.onHide}>close</Button>
</Modal.Footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put them into a function?

```
clickHandler = ()=>{
    this.props.onHide();
    this.setState({userDetailModalShow: true}
}
```

```
 <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="danger" onClick={()=>{()=> clickHandler()}}
                    }>User Detail</Button>
                      <Button variant="danger" onClick={this.props.onHide}>close</Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write inline code like this as there may be syntax and scope error

```
onClick={() => { func1(); func2();}}
```